# Which Exchange Certificate for Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, certificate, exchange-server

[Exchange-Certificates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMOxP.png)

Which certificate do I have to add to my (Docker) Gitlab-Server so I can send mails?
Or do I have make a self-signed-certificate?

```
gitlab_rails['smtp_ca_file'] = '/path/to/your/cacert.pem'
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding the purpose of this setting. `gitlab_rails['smtp_ca_file']` is used to help ensure that GitLab properly trusts **your** SMTP server (which is not provided by GitLab/Omnibus!). This is necessary, for example, in a situation where you may have a SMTP server which utilizes a (potentially self-signed) certificate that is not otherwise trusted under a well-known/trusted CA.

In this context, it would not make sense to generate a certificate -- the certificate should be provided to you by another entity, such as your company mail server or a company Certificate Authority (CA). See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/368123/453397) for details on how you can find the certificate you need using the `openssl` command (if you can't retrieve it directly from your server configuration or otherwise get it from some other source).

If your mail server uses a certificate issued by a well-known/trusted CA, this setting is not needed.

Comment: in the screenshot you can see three certificates, which one do I have to trust?